# Python / Collections - Remove elements that appear same number of times

Tags: python, collections

Example 1:

```
import collections

list = ['Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Jhon', 'Jhon', 'Rob', 'Rob', 'Carl', 'Carl']
list_counter = collections.Counter(list)
>> Counter({'Mike': 3, 'Rob': 2, 'Jhon': 2, 'Carl': 2})
```

Example 2:

```
import collections
list = ['Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Jhon', 'Jhon', 'Rob', 'Rob']
list_counter = collections.Counter(list)
>> Counter({'Sam': 4, 'Mike': 3, 'Rob': 2, 'Jhon': 2})
```

All I want to do is to verify if in the list occours 2 or more elements the same number of times, and delete them.

In example 1 Rob, Jhon and Carl would be removed, they are 3 elements that appears 2 times in the list. In example 2 Rob and Jhon would be removed, while Sam and Mike would be ok and left in the list. If in the list appears only 1 element (for example Jhon n times), nothing would be removed.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Actually I have no idea, I only know that I can easly retrive every element occurence with list_counter["Sam"] for example

Comment: Are you deleting elements with only count 2, no more no less?

Comment: What happens with  `Counter({'Mike': 3, 'Rob': 2, 'Jhon': 2, 'Carl': 2,"foo":4,"bar":4})`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ... If I've understood well OP's intention here, then it should be `Counter({'Mike':3})` ... nop?

Comment: @IronFist, yep, I thought the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all names that appear at the same frequency at least two times:

```
import collections

lst = ['Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Jhon', 'Jhon', 'Rob', 'Rob', 'Carl', 'Carl',
       "foo","foo","foo","foo","bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"]
list_counter = collections.Counter(lst)

# count the frequency 
times = collections.Counter(list_counter.values())

# keep names that do not appear at the same frequency as any other names
lst[:] = [name for name,v  in list_counter.items() if times[v] < 2]
print(lst)
```

which would leave you with:

```
['Mike']
```

If you want to also makes sure the count is not 1:

```
[name for name, v  in list_counter.items() if v == 1 or times[v] < 2]
```

If you want to keep all the Mikes then iterate over the list:

```
import collections

lst = ['Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Jhon', 'Jhon', 'Rob', 'Rob', 'Carl', 'Carl',
       "foo","foo","foo","foo","bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"]
list_counter = collections.Counter(lst)
times = collections.Counter(list_counter.values())

lst[:] = [name for name in lst if times[list_counter[name]] < 2]
print(lst)
```

Which would give you:

```
 ['Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike']
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach was to first group all elements with same `count` into `defaultdict` object, then build your resulting dictionary based on a filtering condition:

```
>>> from collections import Counter, defaultdict  
>>>
>>> lst = ['Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Jhon', 'Jhon', 'Rob', 'Rob', 'Carl', 'Carl']
>>> c = Counter(lst)
>>> c
Counter({'Mike': 3, 'Carl': 2, 'Rob': 2, 'Jhon': 2})
>>>
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> 
>>> for k,v in c.items():
        d[v].append(k)
>>> 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {2: ['Jhon', 'Rob', 'Carl'], 3: ['Mike']})
>>>
>>> result = dict((*v,k) for k,v in d.items() if len(v) < 2)
>>> result
{'Mike': 3}
>>>
```

Comment: This is actually O(n^2), using Counters to do the counting  is O(n)

Comment: Build your counts first then do your lookups.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham...Thanks for the head's up :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find all of the different amounts by using `.values()` and then making a list comprehension of the values that appear `>=` 2 times:

```
values = collections.Counter(list_counter.values())
result = [item for item in list if values[item] >= 2]
```

I wouldn't use `list` as a variable name, however, because it shadows the built-in type.

Answer (score 0):

if I get it right you want to keep those names what occure more than 2 times.
In this case:

```
[x for x,y in list_counter.iteritems() if y>2]
```

Comment: It's not "more than 2 times"; it's the same number of times as something else.  Notice, `Mike` stays put in both examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
your_list = ['Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Jhon', 'Jhon', 'Rob', 'Rob']
list_counter = collections.Counter(your_list)
filtered_list = [item for item in your_list if list_counter.get(item) != 2]
result = list(set(filtered_list))
```

The filtered list is an python list comprehension way to compare if your list item has counter != 2.

In case of example two.

['Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike']

now doing

list(set(filtered_list))

['Mike']

You should not name your variables like 'list'.